# Why is it better to use environment variable when we are still going to hard code it in code

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I would like to all the Python seniors to please explain me the actual usage of environment variable and how it is considered to be more useful in run time then constants in program when we are still going to hard code it in program. I am attaching code snippet of API calls I am making. Please explain how, when and why should we use environment variables.

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import os

APPLICATION_ID = "appid"
APPLICATION_KEYS = "appkey"
EXERCISE_END_POINT = "exercise end point "
SHEET_END_POINT = "sheety end point"
AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN ='Bearer token'
GENDER = "MALE"
WEIGHT_KG = "92"
HEIGHT = "176.784"
AGE = "40"
# USERNAME = 'user name'
# PASSWORD = 'password'

# Set environment variables
os.environ['API_USER'] = 'user name'
os.environ['API_PASSWORD'] = 'password'

# Get environment variables
USERNAME = os.getenv('API_USER')
PASSWORD = os.environ.get('API_PASSWORD')

DATE_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y"
LOCAL_TIME_FORMAT = "%X"




headers = {
    "x-app-id": APPLICATION_ID,
    "x-app-key": APPLICATION_KEYS,
}

exercise_input = input("Tell us which exercise you did today?: ")
params = {
    "query": exercise_input,
    "gender":"female",
    "weight_kg": WEIGHT_KG,
    "height_cm": HEIGHT,
    "age": AGE
}

response = requests.post(EXERCISE_END_POINT, json=params, headers=headers)
result = response.json()
# print(result)
exercise = result['exercises'][0]['name']
exercise = exercise.title()
duration = result['exercises'][0]['duration_min']
calories = result['exercises'][0]['nf_calories']

print(exercise,duration,calories)
date = datetime.now()
formatted_date = date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
time = date.strftime(LOCAL_TIME_FORMAT)

para = {
    'workout':
        {
            'date': formatted_date,
            'time': time,
            'exercise': exercise,
            'duration': duration,
            'calories': calories,
        }
}

# Basic Authentication
auth=(
      USERNAME,
      PASSWORD,
  )

# response = requests.post(SHEET_END_POINT,json=para, auth=auth)
# result = response.json()
# print(result)

# Bearer Token Authentication
bearer_headers = {
    'Authorization':AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN,
}

# Posting
response = requests.post(SHEET_END_POINT,json=para, headers=bearer_headers)
result = response.json()
print(result)
```

Comment: Hard-coding API keys makes them easier to leak out, like the keys you just posted before your edit.  If you search the news, people have make the same mistake publishing them to github.  Also, if variables are in the env then you can have development-test-qa servers using different keys and endpoints to talk to dev or qa servers.

Comment: Note that when you edit something, the previous version is still available in the editor history. Now we all know your API key, so you should discard it and generate a new one.

Comment: ^ even if you delete the question, someone might already have copied the keys to do bad things with them.

Comment: The only use I can think of for setting and reading in the same program is that they are available to child processes and programs run from this one.

Comment: Also, if keys are not in code then key rotation can be done without a code change.

Comment: More generally, you'd write your program to use, not write, environment variables. Some sort of master .py or shell program would set the variables. The idea is that the top level runner is highly controlled while the script that only reads the environment variables can be posted anywhere.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I understood the concern regarding leak of the API key in hard coding and the editor history. I have one more question, how do we set and use environment variables as despite seeing a lot of examples on net. I couldn't do it. I request you all to please explain it in detail.  Thanks